# Get data from inside a json dependent on a variable inside

Tags: javascript, json

Say I have this random json file:

```
    {
  "categoryName": "Appetizers & Sides",
  "categories": [
    {
      "categoryID": "294",
      "parentID": "304",
      "subjectID": "7",
      "categoryName": "Apps and Side Dishes (Laura)",
      "categoryDescription": "Learn to make amazing appetizers and side dishes with Laura in the Kitchen.",
      "videosCount": "101",
      "forumCategoryID": "163"
    },
    {
      "categoryID": "285",
      "parentID": "304",
      "subjectID": "7",
      "categoryName": "Side Dishes",
      "categoryDescription": "Side dish recipes for salads, vegetables, sauces with Hilah cooking.",
      "videosCount": "38",
      "forumCategoryID": "163"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get the categoryName if i have the categoryID ?

Much appreciated,

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var obj =  {
  "categoryName": "Appetizers & Sides",
  "categories": [
    {
      "categoryID": "294",
      "parentID": "304",
      "subjectID": "7",
      "categoryName": "Apps and Side Dishes (Laura)",
      "categoryDescription": "Learn to make amazing appetizers and side dishes with Laura in the Kitchen.",
      "videosCount": "101",
      "forumCategoryID": "163"
    },
    {
      "categoryID": "285",
      "parentID": "304",
      "subjectID": "7",
      "categoryName": "Side Dishes",
      "categoryDescription": "Side dish recipes for salads, vegetables, sauces with Hilah cooking.",
      "videosCount": "38",
      "forumCategoryID": "163"
    }
  ]
};
var parentId = "304";
var catId = obj.categories.filter(function(item){ return item.parentID === parentId })[0].categoryID;
```

BTW: filter may return an empty collection if it didn't find the result.

Comment: what is the function of the [0] if i may ask?

Comment: filter returns an array and since you know that the parentId is unique, then it will always return an array with a single element. That's why I use [0].